# How can i access left or right patch of Turtles in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I know that we can acess `patch-right-and-ahead`, `patch-left-and-ahead`, `patch-here`, but what about right and left of patch-here?

Comment: Do you mean relative or absolute right?

Comment: @mattsap Im not sure, what re difference between those, but i guess is absolute right

Comment: Imagine you're on the grid facing right. If you had a compass and looked right from your position, it would point south. South would be the absolute direction, whereas you were looking right from your position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `patch-at` which Reports the patch at (dx, dy) from the caller (the east and west).

So, `patch-at 1 0` and `patch-at -1 0` would get the patches to the east and west respectively.

Alternatively, you could get the relative right and left of an agent using:  `patch-right-and-ahead 90 1` and  `patch-right-and-ahead -90 1`

Comment: Another alternative for right cell could it be `patch-right-and-ahead -270 1` ?

Comment: I would suggest saying "east" and "west" instead of "absolute right" and "absolute left".